# Trying to user BeautifulSoup to scrape href from table?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

the structure of the html table is as following

```
<table class="tableFile2" summary="Results">
         <tbody><tr class="">
<td nowrap="nowrap">10-K</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1411579/000141157920000027/0001411579-20-000027-index.htm" id="documentsbutton">&nbsp;Documents</a>&nbsp; 
</td>
</tr>
```

what i am trying to do is extract the href and appending it to a list but the list stays empty?
this is what i did

```
links_list = []
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,"lxml")
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"tableFile2"})
tr = table.find_all("tr")

for each_tr in tr:
    td = each_tr.find_all("td")
    
    for each_td in td:
        #print(each_td.text)
        a = each_td.find_All("a")
        if(each_td.text =="10-K"):
            print(each_td.text)
            links_list.append(each_td.get('href'))
            
links_list
```

the purpose is to get the link to the 10-k forms from SEC website

Comment: What is the output of `each_td.get('href')`?

Comment: what's the base_url?